# entlib Invalid TraceListenerData type

Tags: c#, logging, configuration, dependency-injection, enterprise-library

I've created a custom listener for Enterprise Library 5 Logging Block, which is recognized by the Configuration Editor, but throws a run-time configuration exception:

### Attempt to Use the Custom Logger

```
    static IUnityContainer _container;
    static LogWriter _writer;
    static IServiceLocator _locator;

    public static void Inf(string message)
    {
        if (_container == null)
        {
            // Create the container
            _container = new UnityContainer();
            // Configurator will read Enterprise Library configuration
            // and set up the container
            var configurator = new UnityContainerConfigurator(_container);
            // Configuration source holds the new configuration we want to use
            // load this in your own code
            IConfigurationSource configSource = new SystemConfigurationSource(true);
            // Configure the container
            EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(configurator, configSource);
            // Wrap in ServiceLocator
            _locator = new UnityServiceLocator(_container);
        }
        if (_writer == null)
        {
            _writer = _locator.GetInstance<LogWriter>();
        }
        if (_writer != null && _container != null)
        {
            LogEntry log = new LogEntry();
            log.Message = message;
            log.Categories.Add("Information");
            log.Severity = TraceEventType.Information;
            _writer.Write(log);
        }
    }
```

### Own TraceListener in dll

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters;

namespace CustomLogger
{
    [ConfigurationElementType(typeof(LoggerCustomData))]
    public class LoggerCustom : TraceListener //CustomTraceListener
    {
        readonly ILogFormatter _formatter;

        public LoggerCustom()
            : this(string.Empty, null)
        {
        }

        public LoggerCustom(string name)
            : this(name, null)
        {
        }

        public LoggerCustom(string name, ILogFormatter formatter)
            : base(name)
        {
            this._formatter = formatter;
        }

        public override void TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, object data)
        {
            if ((Filter == null) || Filter.ShouldTrace(eventCache, source, eventType, id, null, null, data, null))
            {
                if (data is LogEntry)
                {
                    if (_formatter != null)
                    {
                        WriteLine(_formatter.Format(data as LogEntry));
                    } else
                    {
                        base.TraceData(eventCache, source, eventType, id, data);
                    }
                } else
                {
                    base.TraceData(eventCache, source, eventType, id, data);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Write(string message)
        {
            Trace.Write(message);
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

### Custom TraceListenerData in dll

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Design;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Properties;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters;

namespace CustomLogger
{
    [ResourceDisplayName(typeof(Resources), "CustomLoggerDataDisplayName")]
    [ResourceDescription(typeof(Resources), "CustomLoggerDataDescription")]
    public class LoggerCustomData : TraceListenerData
    {
        private const string FormatterNameProperty = "formatter";

        public LoggerCustomData()
            : this("unnamed", null, TraceOptions.None)
        {
        }

        public LoggerCustomData(string name)
            : this(name, null, TraceOptions.None)
        {
        }

        public LoggerCustomData(string name, string formatterName)
            : this(name, formatterName, TraceOptions.None)
        {
        }

        protected LoggerCustomData(string name, string formatterName, TraceOptions traceOutputOptions)
            : base(name, typeof(LoggerCustom), traceOutputOptions, SourceLevels.All)
        {
            ListenerDataType = typeof(LoggerCustomData);
            Formatter = formatterName;
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty(FormatterNameProperty, IsRequired = false),
        Reference(typeof(NameTypeConfigurationElementCollection<FormatterData, CustomFormatterData>), typeof(FormatterData)),
        ResourceDisplayName(typeof(Resources), "CustomLoggerDataFormatterDisplayName"),
        ResourceDescription(typeof(Resources), "CustomLoggerDataFormatterDescription")]
        public string Formatter
        {
            get { return (string)base[FormatterNameProperty]; }
            set { base[FormatterNameProperty] = value; }
        }

        protected override Expression<Func<TraceListener>> GetCreationExpression()
        {
            return () =>
                new LoggerCustom(Name,
                    Container.ResolvedIfNotNull<ILogFormatter>(Formatter));
        }
    }
}
```

### app.config addition generated by ConfEditor

```
  <add name="CustomLoggerDataDisplayName" type="CustomLogger.LoggerCustom, CustomLogger, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    listenerDataType="CustomLogger.LoggerCustomData, CustomLogger, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" formatter="Text Formatter Plain" />
```

### Exception at .ConfigureContainer(configurator, configSource)

Invalid TraceListenerData type in configuration 'listenerDataType="CustomLogger.LoggerCustomData, CustomLogger, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"'.

Why does it not work ? :( :(

p.s. this post is an evolution of [entlib CustomTraceListener unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259951/entlib-customtracelistener-unresolved/7261057)

Comment: turns out the issue was lack of the CustomLogger.dll in the application output i.e. Configuration Editor played with it fine because it was in the enterprise library bin folder, but the dll needs to be also in the client application folder: i assumed at first that enterprise library would include it automatically somehow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case defaultCategory="Important"  I have changed to  defaultCategory="" in the Configuration first line, then worked fine.